# How to initialise nested form attributes in ROR app which uses devise after sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am new to Ruby on rails and building an application where user can add his education history after signing up. I am using two edit forms, one default devise edit view for password or email update and second edit user view which i have created along with users_controller for updating other fields like name etc. I am using nested form for adding education details. The problem is how do i initialise the education model because i want the user to add education details just after sign up. i dont want the user to prompt user with all these fields in the sign up field.
there is no error but no education fields are showing.

the main issue is that i am using the devise for registration and custom edit form for adding education fields. do i need to write custom new method?

here is the code in my app/views/users/edit.html.erb

```
        <div class="input-field">
             <%= f.label :name %>
             <%= f.text_field :name %>
         </div>

        <div class="input-field">
            <%= f.label :date_of_birth %><br />
            <%=f.date_field(:date_of_birth, :class => "datepicker")%>
        </div>


        <div class="input-field">
            <%= f.label :city %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :city, autofocus: true %>
        </div>

         <div class="input-field">
            <%= f.label :about_me %>
            <%= f.text_area :about_me, autofocus: true %>
        </div>

        <%= f.fields_for :educations do |ff| %>
            <div>
                <%= ff.label :institution_name %>
                <%= ff.text_field :institution_name %>
            </div>

            <div>
                <%= ff.label :course %>
                <%= ff.text_field :course %>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field">
                <%= f.label :from %><br />
                <%=f.date_field(:from, :class => "datepicker")%>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field">
                <%= f.label :to %><br />
                <%=f.date_field(:to, :class => "datepicker")%>
            </div>

        <% end %>
        <%= f.submit "Save changes"%>
   <% end %>
```

here is my userss_controller.rb

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!
   before_action :prepare_schools
   before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]

   def new
   end

   def index
     @users = User.all
   end

   def show
     @user= User.find(params[:id])
   end

   def edit
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
   end

   def update
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
  end

 def correct_user
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user==(@user)
 end

 private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name,:date_of_birth,:city,:about_me,
          :educations_attributes => [:id,:institution_name, :from, :to])
    end

    def prepare_schools
       @schools = School.all
    end
 end

here is my USER model

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
   # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
     devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable


     enum user_type: [:student, :teacher, :principal, :other]

    has_one :school
    has_many :educations,  dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :educations, :allow_destroy => true,
                                  :reject_if     => :all_blank,
                                  :allow_destroy => true

    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    validates :user_type, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    validates :school_id, presence: true
    validates :date_of_birth, presence: true
    validates :about_me,  length: { maximum: 1000 }
    validates :city,  length: { maximum: 100 }
 end
```

here is my EDUCATION model(nested model)

```
  class Education < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :educations
     validates_presence_of :user
  end
```

Edit(suggested by pavan): here is the params passing through the form, the nested attributes are absent

```
    !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
     utf8: "✓"
     _method: patch
                                                                                    authenticity_token:1gHK22TcGLsPjIdb/
      user: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
       name: ''
       date_of_birth: '1992-03-03'
       city: delhi
       about_me: i am what i am!!
       commit: Save changes
       controller: users
       action: update
       id: '3'
```

P.S. i tried using formhelper functions but that didn't help.

Comment: Can you update the question with the `params` generated in the server logs?

Answer (score 0):

In `new` or `edit` action, you can build `educations` objects and it will initialize the nested attributes. like below -

```
def new
  current_user.eductions.build #or @user.educations.build
  # it will initialize a eduction object in form

end
```

Comment: i tried this but no help. new action is never called as user registration is handled by devise so new method never gets called ,but still i tried this as suggested by you. i also tried to put the line of  code in edit method but still it doesn't work

Comment: i am getting a NoMethodError in UsersController#edit                                      else
        match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
        match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
      end
    end